# What is the fastest way to push all 64-bit registers onto the stack?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I am beginning to write some assembly. What is the fastest way to push and pop all 64-bit registers to the stack in x86-64? I know pusha will save the state of all 32-bit general purpose registers.

I want to save the state(using cdecl convention) of all the registers I will use(I will use all 64-bit registers).

Thanks.

Comment: Note that the "duplicate" question is tagged `isr` (interrupt service routine). For regular user-mode code, it may not be necessary to push all registers. For example with the Windows 64bit [calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx), rcx, rdx, r8 & r9 are used for the first 4 parameters, and can be clobbered by the called routine. Likewise r10 & r11 are scratch and can be clobbered, and rax is either the return value, or scratch (neither requires a save). I'm sure linux (if that's what you use) has similar characteristics. Save just what you must.